# Replit custom domain shows verified but the link doesnt work

Tags: replit

I got a free domain from freenom and want to link it to replit. I watched videos and linked with cloudflare. I added nameservers too.

**Replit shows the link is verified**

[image]

**But the problem is:**

[image]

It shows "This page isn't working" even though it's been more than an hour. I did everything correct and as shown in the video. [Youtube video that I followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sf2WmobLgZw). The person in the video says it should work after 5 - 10 minutes at *7:39*. But it's been more than an hour.

Please help if anybody has a solution to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it. Just go to SSL/TLS and set the encryption mode to full. It worked for me and I just had to refresh the page to see the site. Hope it helps :)

[image]